# Make Notepad++ highlight all occurances of finished word after hitting space or punctuation?

Tags: notepad++

I find when writing or editing, whatever it may be, I wind up repeating words that I'm not aware of repeating. The proximity of the repeated words are too close, and it winds up sounding clumsy. This can even be missed upon proof-reading. "Author blindness" or "proofreading blindness" or something, whatever that effect is that doesn't affect fresh eyes.

Example: Though it's important that you keep in mind X, for instance, remember that Y should always remain your primary focus. There are exceptions, though. You should keep in mind Z on rare occasions, for instance.

Reusing "though," "keep in mind," and "for instance" so close to the first usages sounds awkward, when "however," "worth noting," or another similar word/phrase would sound better. That's just off the top of my head; I'm sure there are better examples, but they aren't coming to mind.

What I'm after is a way to set things in Notepad++ so that after you type a word and either hit a space or a punctuation, all previous instances of that word you just finished are highlighted. The highlighting disappears as you begin your next word.

That way, as you type, you can get immediate visual feedback for how close the last use of the word you just typed is. I've hunted for a program that does this, to no avail. Ideally, I would want to set parameters based on imported phrases, for example "keep in mind" being treated as a single unit if or when it recurs. However, it would be extremely useful just to have the previous word's occurrences in the document be highlighted, where a space or a punctuation triggers the highlight.

Is this possible to do in Notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

That type of functionality is not possible. But something you can do is use regular expressions to check your document for places that you have done that.

In Notepad++, use Ctrl+F to open up the search dialogue, and make sure the same options are selected as here:

[image: Notepad++ finding repeated phrases]

Search for this regular expression to find occurrences of two- or three-word phrases that are within 300 characters of each other:

```
([a-zA-Z']{2,} [a-zA-Z']{2,}( [a-zA-Z']{2,})?).{1,300}\1
```

When you click "Find Next", it will highlight the text from the first occurrence of the phrase to the second occurrence as in the screenshot.

If you have a pre-made list of words and/or phrases that you want to check for, such as

```
albeit,for instance,however,on the other hand,keep in mind
```

Then you can search for those using this regular expression:

```
(albeit|for instance|however|on the other hand|keep in mind).{1,300}\1
```

If you save a copy of the regular expression, then you can just keep a running list of words/phrases that you want to search for and keep adding more to it as they come to mind.